# Why is my react app so inefficient in mobile browser?

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I have created a web app in ReactJS. I have used the following libraries(only the important ones are listed):

1. react-router-app
2. redux
3. redux-saga
4. axios
5. react-responsive
6. material-ui/*

I have used create-react-app to bootstrap the project.

On one of the pages I have a list. As you scroll down the list new records are downloaded as you reach the end of the list. When too many records are loaded the app starts to lag (On cell phones and iPad). The same does not happen in desktop/laptop browsers.

Why does this happen and also is there a way to "optimize" the app in this scenario? If yes, please share your insights.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really tried this, but my intuition says that the below link is the solution:

[Virtualize long lists](https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#virtualize-long-lists)